# Going from iterating record to GetRows() - Is it possible to rs("id", counter)?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am getting a huge amount of data from my database which I before iterated through in a recordset like this:

```
sql = "select * from table"
set rs = conn.execute(sql)

if not rs.eof then
  do until rs.eof
    id = rs("id")
    fullname = rs("fullname")

    response.write("<a href='/" & id & "'>Hi " & fullname & ".<br />")
  rs.movenext
loop
```

Now I am using a static recordset using GetRows() like this:

```
sql = "select * from table"
set rssql = conn.execute(sql)

if not rssql.eof then
  rs = rssql.getrows()
end if

rssql.close

if isarray(rs) then
  for counter = lbound(rs) to ubound(rs)
    id = rs(0, counter)
    fullname = rs(1, counter)

    response.write("<a href='/" & id & "'>Hi " & fullname & ".<br />")
  next
end if
```

Is it really not possible to do something like rs("id", counter) instead of using static numbers? I have a dynamic amount of coloumns (created by the system) in my table and it is very dynamic which of them I need. The number of coloumns I need in each rows are specificed by another coloumn in the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetRows` returns a vanilla array & as such is only addressable by a numeric index.

If you feel you need to dispose of the connection as soon as possible for some reason, you can fully populate the recordset and disconnect is as [describe here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184397).

(You can always use the initial recordset to populate another array or collection with the column names via the `.Fields` collection)

Comment: I created another array with the names using .fields and afterwards a function to find the arraynumber.. thanks for the ideas! :)

Comment: A [`Scripting.Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28VS.84%29.aspx) where the key is the column name and the value is the array index might be easier to use.

Comment: I used an array with the array index being the ID and the value the name, thereafter I created a very simple function to go through it. It worked perfectly and the whole thing boosted my application from being 10 minutes to load to 10 seconds. So I'm pretty happy ;)

Answer (score 1):

`rs.Fields(counter).Name` will give you access to column names. Unfortunately `getrows()` does not create an associative array, so you cannot look up data by column name.